# How to override jQuery global functions for my plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, overriding

I have created a plugin that creates a **check box image** based based on a hidden field. I would like to override the `is()` function... is that possible? I'm basically using an image to mock a checkbox.

Html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="box" />
```

Create the plugin for the hidden field:

```
$('#box').myCheckbox();
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
$('#box').is(':checked');
```

**Is it possible to override the `is()` function in my plugin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep :)

```
           (function() {
              var proxied = jQuery.fn.is;
              jQuery.fn.is= function() {
                //do your things here
                return proxied.apply(this, arguments);//call the default is here
              };
            })();
```

btw `:checked` is already supported by default

so if u had

$('#checkbox').is(':checked');// return true/false depending if the checkbox is ticked or not don't over complicate things as you will pull ur hair out later on when u forgot that u made this overriding changes :)

Comment: I wasn't complete in my question. I failed to mention that I'm mocking the checkbox by using an image.

Comment: Works like a charm! `var proxied = jQuery.fn.is;
$.fn.is = function () {

 var t = $(this);

 if (t.data('myCheckbox') !== undefined) {
  if (arguments.length === 1 && arguments[0] === ':checked') {
   return t.data('myCheckbox').getState() === 1;
  }
 }

 return proxied.apply(this, arguments); 
};`

Answer (score 3):

You can extend jQuery's selectors and add new ones.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/

For example:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    inline: function(a) {
        return $(a).css('display') === 'inline';
    }
});
```

That allows you to do:

`$(':inline'); // Selects ALL inline elements`

`$('a:inline'); // Selects ALL inline anchors`

EDIT:

In your case, to emulate the checkbox, first grab the code from jquery :checked... Which is:

```
return elem.checked === true;
```

Then

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    checked: function(a) {
        if(a.isMySpecialCheckbox()) return a.hasAPropertyThatSignifiesChecked;
        else return elem.checked === true;
    }
});
```

Try that, I haven't tried it, but it should work.

Comment: I like your example, but will it work to override the 'is' function?

Comment: Well what you'd be overwriting / adding is the selector.  So you can change what :checked does... or you can add your own selector like :hiddenChecked.  It's usually best practice NOT to override internal library functions.  You never know what other bug you'll introduce.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I'll need this too... but Val gave the right answer to the question.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It doesn't seem to override the 'checked' expression. When I make it 'checked2' everything works though.

Comment: @AlexandruPetrescu ` return $(a).css('display') === 'inline'` correct me if I am wrong but it will not return the element it will `return true|false` so in other words, `$(':inline');` will just return true or false if there are any elements with inline in it..., using the `.filter()` perhaps could be a better choice...

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `.attr('checked')`?

Comment: Because I what to emulate a "real" checkbox (jQuery wise). But I'm actually using an image.